# While using vuforia reduce the file size of the APK to minimum possible value

Tags: vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

Hope you all are doing well.
We are currently building an Android app and we want to reduce the file size of the APK to the minimum possible value.
We noticed that the 'libVuforiaEngine.so' file takes up around 15.5MB.
Is there a way to reduce this further? We are planning on using only Object Tracking and no other features so if there is a way to remove those additional features and further reduce the file size then it would be great.

Looking forward to hearing from you!
Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kNAK.png)

We are loading streaming assets through OBB assets. We need to reduce the size even more. We noticed that the 'libVuforiaEngine.so' file takes up around 15.5MB.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to exclude features from the Vuforia Engine library in order to reduce the size of the .so.